# Finding the MLE for a piecewise function

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, point-estimation, piecewise-pdf

I am attempting to find the MLE for the two parameters (i.e. $\alpha, \beta$) in the following piecewise function, but I am slightly confused as to how to proceed through this question:

$$
P(X_i \leq x | \alpha,\beta) =  
\begin{cases} 
      0 & \text{if } &  x \leq 0 \\ 
      (\frac x\beta)^\alpha & \text{if } & 0\leq x \leq \beta \\
     1 & \text{if } & x > \beta, 
   \end{cases} 
$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are postive. Find the MLEs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I defined $\theta=(\alpha, \beta)$ and the likelihood function $$L(\theta) = f(x\mid\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^\alpha} {\beta^{n\alpha}}I\{0<x<\beta\} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n 1 I\{x>\beta\}.$$ I am confused as to how I should incorporate the function when $x>\beta)$. I know I should take the log-likelihood afterward if the likelihood function is rough.

Comment: The function you wrote looks like a CDF.  You need to change it to a PDF in order to use it in the likelihood function.

Comment: I have updated the function let me know if there is another issue. Thanks!

Comment: The first indicator is missing the $i$ in the $x_i$'s. And there is no $x_i>\beta$ by definition of the cdf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
$$
L(\theta) = f(x\mid\theta) = \xcancel{ \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^\alpha} {\beta^{n\alpha}}I\{0<x<\beta\} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n 1 I\{x>\beta\}}.
$$
First you have the density $f(x) = \alpha \left( \dfrac x\beta\right)^{\alpha-1} \cdot \dfrac1\beta$ for $0<x<\beta.$

(In many contexts, I prefer to write $f(x)\,dx = \alpha\left( \dfrac x\beta \right)^{\alpha-1} \cdot \dfrac{dx}\beta,$ since that shows that every $\beta$ belongs with an $x$ and suggests the appropriate substitution $\alpha u^{\alpha-1}\, du.$)

Then
\begin{align}
L(\theta) = L(\alpha,\beta) = {} & \prod_{i=1}^n \left( \alpha\left( \frac{x_i}\beta \right)^{\alpha-1} \cdot \frac 1\beta\cdot \mathbf 1(0\le x_i\le\beta) \right) \\
& \text{Notice that no superscript $n$ appears} \\ & \text{among the things that are multiplied here.} \\[8pt]
= {} & \left(\frac\alpha{\beta^\alpha} \right)^n \left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^{\alpha-1} \mathbf 1\left(\left(\max_{i=1}^n x_i\right) \le \beta \right)
\end{align}
As a function of $\beta,$ this increases as $\beta$ decreases **until** $\beta$ gets all the way down to $\max_{i=1}^n x_i.$ As soon as $\beta$ is less than that, the whole thing becomes $0.$

Thus the MLE of $\beta$ is $\max_{i=1}^n x_i.$

Now set $\beta$ equal to that and then seek the maximizing value of $\alpha.$

Comment: Thanks this helps, it helps to view it in this manner.